# Will my personal files be lost

Tags: system-installation

If I install Ubuntu in C-drive containing windows using option ' Erase disk and Install Ubuntu' will my personal files,folders,photos, music will be lost? 
It's ok that windows will be removed from my desktop.
Please help me out

Comment: yes, if you "erase the disk and install Ubuntu" all your files will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

The are two options.

1. Backup your personal files, install Ubuntu and copy them back.
2. Do a manual partitioning and keep the old "Disk D" or similar Windows partition with your personal files.

The second option is not very good because keeping a NTFS partition without Windows may cause problems in the future.